# Google Maps - disable search box

Tags: google-maps

I am using google maps to diplay driving directions to a dynamic location that is pulled from a database. The call to google looks like this

http://maps.google.com/?q=dynamicaddress

I have been trying to find a way to disable the search box on the top of the page and also remove the top black bar that is there by default.

I want the user to stay in the maps page and not wander to google search and potentially land in an unsafe site.

Thanks!

SMJ

Comment: You want to do this on a system that created or own google?

Comment: Has anyone figured this out?